# Delphi DLL Dynamic Error raise to many consecutive exception

Tags: delphi, dll

I found this source code from a Delphi sample codes, and
I am adding a control or component inside a Delphi dynamic DLL, I can't figure it out,

```
library DLLEntryLib;

uses
  SysUtils,
  Windows,
  Dialogs,
  Classes,
  msHTML,
  SHDocVw;

type
TMyWeb = class(TWebBrowser)
constructor create(Aowner: TComponent); override;
end;

var
web: TMyWeb;

// Initialize properties here
constructor TMyWeb.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
inherited Create(Self);
end;

procedure getweb;
begin
    web := TmyWeb.create(nil);
    web.Navigate('http://mywebsite.com');
end;


procedure xDLLEntryPoint(dwReason: DWord);
begin
  case dwReason of
    DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    begin
    getweb; //I THINK THE ERROR IS HERE, HOW TO WORK THIS OUT?
    ShowMessage('Attaching to process');
    end;
    DLL_PROCESS_DETACH: ShowMessage('Detaching from process');
    DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:  MessageBeep(0);
    DLL_THREAD_DETACH:  MessageBeep(0);
  end;
end;

begin
  { First, assign the procedure to the DLLProc variable }
  DllProc := @xDLLEntryPoint;
  { Now invoke the procedure to reflect that the DLL is attaching to the
    process }
  xDLLEntryPoint(DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH);
end.


//IN MY APPLICATION FORM.
procedure TMainForm.btnLoadLibClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
if LibHandle = 0 then
begin
LibHandle := LoadLibrary('DLLENTRYLIB.DLL');
if LibHandle = 0 then
  raise Exception.Create('Unable to Load DLL');
end
else
MessageDlg('Library already loaded', mtWarning, [mbok], 0);
end;
```

How do I get rid of the error?
raise to many consicutive exception

Comment: Perhaps a call to CoInitialize() ?

Comment: Did you try debugging the DLL to try and find out where the exception is being raised? (Open your DLL project, and set a breakpoint as usual. In `Run->Parameters`, put your application (not DLL) in the `Host Application`. Close the dialog and hit F9 to run your application until the breakpoint is hit, and then single step through the code using F8 or F7.

Comment: The `xDllEntryPoint` function runs while the **OS loader lock** is held. In that state, you're not really supposed to do much at all because not all the process's libraries are fully loaded or unloaded. However, you're creating *an entire Internet Explorer control* and initiating network activity. Stop doing that. Take all that code out of the DLL's entry function and put it in a normal function that you export from the DLL. Call that exported function from your application after `LoadLibrary` returns.

Comment: You *think* the error is there? Why don't you know for certain? If you think the error is in that function, and you wrote the function, can't you be more specific about *where* in that function the error occurs?

Comment: @Ken White, the error is in the line getweb, because if I removed it, its fine to call the dll.  This is the purpose of the project to load a dynamic dll with the webbrowser hidden.  I used the coinitialize and seems to work, no error but hangs the application.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. **Did you step through in the debugger?** If you do, you can catch the **first** exception, and see what's causing it. Fixing that will probably remove the *too many exceptions* as well.

Comment: @XenKid Naturally if you remove the only line of code that does anything, the problem goes away.

Comment: @ken White, yes i try it, the cpu debugger shows, but i dont know wheres really the error line, all i know if i remove the getweb function line, it removes the error, im a delphi newbie and i cant fine the error.

Comment: @XenKid Stop doing things in `DllMain`. End. Of. Story.

Comment: @Arnaud Bouchez, you helped a lot, I dont see the +1 for you.  but everyone helped too. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```
inherited Create(Self);
```

you should write

```
inherited Create(AOwner);
```

You are asking the control to own itself. That just cannot work. That quite possibly leads to a non-terminated recursion if the constructor fails.

The other big problem is that you are creating a web browser control inside `DllMain`. That's a very big no-no. You'll want to stop doing that. Move that code into a separate exported function. Do nothing in `DllMain`.

Presumably the caller has already initialized COM. If not, you will need to ensure that the caller does so. If the caller is a VCL forms app then COM will be initialized automatically.

Comment: are you suggesting to make a static dll?  but static dll is called directly when the application runs, but if i used dynamic the dll can be loaded depending if you want it. like pressing a button.

Comment: No that's not what I'm suggesting. I am telling you that you cannot create a web browser control in `DllMain`. You can load your DLL however you like. But don't do anything in `DllMain`.

Comment: It's not remotely impossible. Call LoadLibrary. Immediately then call your exported function.

Comment: ok, can that be done in dynamic dll? using exports? i think exports is only for static dll?

Comment: There's no such thing as dynamic DLLs and static DLLs. There are just DLLs. Load them at process load time with implicit linking. Or load them at runtime with LoadLibrary. No matter what, don't do anything in `DllMain`. Export functions. Load them with `GetProcAddress`. What are you actually trying to do?